# gcp cloud functios: do i want a persistent http connection?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a simple cloud function to call a 3rd party API.

I'm reading this 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking

and i'm wondering if I need to maintain a persistent connection to the 3rd party API? The frequency of my use case low at present.

Wouldn't the 3rd party API not like this because I'm constantly connected to them for no reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not required to maintain an open socket at all.  It's an optimization that may save you time and money.

You should ask the third party API provider what they think.  No one here can speak for all of them.  It's likely that their services are programmed to accept or deny persistently open connections with respect to their own policy.  That is to say, if you keep an open connection for longer than they'd like, they'd simply shut it down and force you to reconnect.

Comment: in the scenario where i'm disconnected and need to reconnect, would the reconnect happen on the next function invocation or at the time of disconnect?

Comment: Depends on how your HTTP client library works.  You might be overanalyzing this.

Comment: this is for my own education. the client library is just the standard http library in the docs. If you don't happen to know I'll just make a new question. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a specific question about the behavior of a specific library, that sounds like a new question.